# React fetching data with axios cors error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch some data using axios and redux. I am using an api.js file which is just exporting mainEventsURL(url for events api data) and then using axios to fetch this url. However when I hard code the api key in to my function which is being exported (and dispatched) it works fine but when I try and pass in process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY and use the dynamic function above it instead I get a cors error.

Why does the application fetch the data fine when hard coding the api key but when I try and use template literal and get the api from .env file I get the cors error?

I will put my redux logic in but there is no problem with the redux code.

```
const base_url = "https://www.example.com/api/v1/";

const main_events = () =>
  `events/search/?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`;

export const mainEventsURL = () => `${base_url}${main_events}`;

// (hard coded api key) 
export const mainEventsURL = () =>
`https://www.example.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=3308f2954454558544533`;
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://example.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET [https://www.example.com/api/v1/()%20=%3E%20%60events/search/?api_key=${Object({%22NODE_ENV%22:%22development%22,%22PUBLIC_URL%22:%22%22,%22WDS_SOCKET_HOST%22:undefined,%22WDS_SOCKET_PATH%22:undefined,%22WDS_SOCKET_PORT%22:undefined,%22FAST_REFRESH%22:true}).REACT_APP_API_KEY}`](https://www.example.com/api/v1/()%20=%3E%20%60events/search/?api_key=$%7BObject(%7B%22NODE_ENV%22:%22development%22,%22PUBLIC_URL%22:%22%22,%22WDS_SOCKET_HOST%22:undefined,%22WDS_SOCKET_PATH%22:undefined,%22WDS_SOCKET_PORT%22:undefined,%22FAST_REFRESH%22:true%7D).REACT_APP_API_KEY%7D%60) net::ERR_FAILED

Actions file

```
import axios from "axios";
import { mainEventsURL } from "../../api"; // url to fetch

export const loadEvents = () => async (dispatch) => {
  // Axios fetch
  const mainEventsData = await axios.get(mainEventsURL());

  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_EVENTS",
    payload: {
      mainEvents: mainEventsData.data.results,
    },
  });
};
```

Reducer file

```
const initState = {
  mainEvents: [],
  searched: [],
};

const eventsReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_EVENTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        mainEvents: action.payload.mainEvents,
      };
    case "FETCH_SEARCHED":
      return {
        ...state,
        searched: action.payload.searched,
      };
    case "CLEAR_SEARCHED":
      return {
        ...state,
        searched: [],
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default eventsReducer;
```

Events component

```
function Events() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadEvents());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const { mainEvents } = useSelector((state) => state.events);
}
```

Comment: make sure to enable cors on the server side so that you can access the api on the different domains.

Comment: That error looks like it's saying it can't find your variable. Can you `console.log(process.env)` and see if it looks the way you think it should look?

Comment: thanks it looks like the process.env is undefined. I wonder why that is